# JApplets and JDialog

Tags: java, applet

I have a japplet which contains an "about" button, which when pressed creates a new JDialog. The idea is that when the user clicks on the about button in the applet they will get a popup window which displays information. This works perfectly fine when i test it from eclipse with the applet viewer, but when i test it in the html form, the button does nothing. The applet runs and works, but the button does not create a new window or respond in any way.

full disclosure: when i say JDialog i actually mean a class i created which extends JDialog and has a method public void paintComponent (Graphics g){ ~~~~ } ... and i also tried with that class extending JFrame instead and had the same problem, it worked in applet viewer but not in the browser.

now my question is, is my thinking wrong, am i going about creating a popup window for a japplet the wrong way, is there a different method i should probably try?

my code is very long, but if there's something you need to see from it to properly answer the question let me know.

Comment: "my code is very long,", but it doesn't have to be long. Create a simple applet with a button. Have that button display a JDialog. It should be about 20 lines of code. Its called a SSCCE (http://sscce.org). If it works, great then you can compare the SCCE code with your real code to see what is different. If it doesn't work, then you have something simple to post on the forum so we can also test it.

Comment: thanks i will keep that in mind, but i figured it out already. Thanks for your time

Answer (score 0):

Are you making sure to set the new popup window to visible?  That could be your problem, or I've heard of problems with Google toolbar not allowing user-initiated popups to appear, but I think that problem was fixed (if you're running an old version of Google toolbar, it may still be an issue).

Answer (score 0):

ok i figure out what the problem is, is an image problem, the DrawingBoard was using io and imageio to load some images.